# What is a noop coroutine?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

The C++20 standard defines a "noop coroutine" in [[coroutine.noop]](http://eel.is/c++draft/coroutine.noop). What is it?
And how is it different from a function whose body is `{ co_return; }`?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the links to the proposal and to the standard. To summarize from these references, a "noop coroutine" is one for which the `resume()` (or `operator()`) and `destroy()` methods have no side-effects.

But `destroy()` on a user-written coroutine always (I think!) has a side effect, namely destroying the coroutine and further calls to the coroutine handle methods including `resume()` and `destroy()` will now be undefined behavior, which is different than no-side-effects behavior.

In summary, there is no way to write a coroutine such that `destroy()` has no side effects, and only the library-provided noop coroutine has this property, correct?

(Updated answers welcome, in response to this update of my question.)

Comment: Can you please provide the reference to where this is mentioned in the standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was proposed here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0913r1.html

Basically, the idea is that

> Having such a coroutine handle allows library writer to perform either
> symmetric or asymmetric control transfer based on runtime
> considerations.

Following code illustrates this idea (from the same proposal):

```
struct Awaiter {
   ...
   auto await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> h) {
     ...
     return cond ? next_coro : noop_coroutine(); 
   }
 };
```

This would not be necessarily different from hand-written noop coroutine, but having one already predefined for you is quite convenient.